# Customizing has_many, belongs_to nested associations json in Active Model Serializer

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-5, active-model-serializers, rails-api

How do I do this

```
class UserSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
  attributes :id, :name. :email

  has_many :posts do                   # I don't want to use PostSerializer
    attributes :id, :title             # /posts/index would show more data
    has_many :comments do              # like created_at, updated_at, edits, other assocs..
      attributes: :id, :content
    end
  end

  belongs_to :category do              # I dont' want to user CategorySerializer
    attributes :id, :name              # /categories/index would show more data
  end                                  # like created_at, no. of users, associations, etc.,
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, but using `serializers`

```
class UserSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
  attributes :id, :name, :email, :user_posts

  def user_posts
    object.posts.map do |post|
      PostSerializer.new(post, only: [:id, :title])
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'user_posts'`. It doesn't jump into the function, in fact, doesn't even recognize the function declaration. I'm using `Ruby 2.3` on `Rails 5.0.0.1` with `Active Model Serializers 0.10.3`

Comment: using `:user_posts` instead helps jump into the function, but doesn't respect `only: [:id, :title]`